# Can't Install Yii Framework Advanced Template on Mac

Tags: php, macos, yii2

I'm new to the Yii framework and I have already installed it on my personal mac computer. The thing is that I cant install it on the mac at the office.

Strangely I follow all the steps the same as on my mac but when I try to download the basic or the advanced template it fails with the following error:

```
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                     
The "http://packagist.org/p/provider-2013$7ae7b77e72316138c9190d26b27e698e9efe24373bdb5d1a968679f5cca0  
e597.json" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request)
```

Also when i run "sudo composer self-update" it says

```
You are already using composer version 9f6fdfd703f433bd0777fd89fb4684908a6c4f06.
```

And running composer diagnose tells me:

```
Checking composer.json: FAIL
require.yiisoft/yii2 : unbound version constraints (>=2.0.6) should be avoided
require.yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap : unbound version constraints (*) should be avoided
require.yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer : unbound version constraints (*) should be avoided
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: OK
Checking http connectivity to packagist: FAIL
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The "http://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request)
Checking https connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking github.com rate limit: OK
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking composer version: OK
```

Also I'm not able to install the composer assets plugging. When running the command it tells me the same [Transport Exception] as when trying to download the template.

Honestly I'v searched everywhere and can't find a solution for this. 
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: You run this command for composer assets `composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:1.0.0"`

Comment: I get this:
Changed current directory to /Users/StationDomain/.composer
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

`[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                                                
  The "http://packagist.org/p/provider-2013$a99577e69e8316d86e887e769f847749e685382f60e880044fa810cb27819b2a.json" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request)`

Answer (score 0):

Well, this error seams to be gone by now ... I just waited to the nextr day, I tried with

```
 sudo composer self-update
```

and it magically updated and I was able to use it.
Don't know what could have been causing this to fail but its working properly now.